# How do use the nested INSERT/SELECT command in this case?

Tags: mysql

I have this command:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (username,profile) SELECT DISTINCT username,profile 
FROM table1 WHERE profile='$profile' and username <> '$sender'
```

My problem is I want this: `INSERT INTO table2 (username,profile,type)` where type is gonna be the same string, say "string"

Important: I only want `username` to be DISTINCT. `profile` and `type` can be the same.
Also, `profile` will always be the same value.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot, regards

Comment: Hi, actually profile is always the same. Let me edit that in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (username, profile, type)
SELECT username, profile, "string"
FROM table1
WHERE profile='$profile' AND username <> '$sender'
GROUP BY username
```

Please please please be **absolutely certain** that `$profile` and `$sender` have been cleaned of possible SQL injection attacks (if that means nothing to you, go read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)).  You'd be *far* better off using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I used mysql_real_escape_string(). It seems that it's good protection, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: It's good, but it has had exploitable bugs in the past; who knows, maybe more will be found?  Parametrized statements are orders of magnitude safer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking into the manuel for `group by` and it doesn't seem like it has the same effect as `DISTINCT` which I want. Is it supposed to anyway?

Comment: In this case, they actually have the same effect.  You can still use `DISTINCT` if you prefer - it's just more work for MySQL as it has to compare three columns for distinct values rather than just one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a huge assumption that you're looking for output something like...

```
UserFred profile1 type1
UserBill profile2 type1
UserJim  profile1 type8
```

You need to apply a GROUP BY statement in the subselect...

```
INSERT INTO table2 (username,profile)
   SELECT DISTINCT username,profile 
   FROM table1 WHERE profile='$profile' and username <> '$sender'
   GROUP BY username;
```